# Is there a way to inherit a variable that uses a argument of its function in a parent class, from a child class without knowing the argument?

Tags: python, class, inheritance

```
class Context: 
    def __init__(self, version = None): 
        self.version = version

class Subparser: 
    def __init__(self):
        self.play = play

    def on_packet(self, packet): 
        self.version = packet.game

class Parser(Subparser): 
    def __init__(self): 
        super().__init__()

    def parse_er_data(self, data): 
        temp = self.version
        breakpoint()


=> print(temp)

=> #the output is always None, but it should not be!
```

For the above, `self.version` in the `parser_er_data()` function will always return the value `None`, and I can see why because it is inheriting self.version from the `Context class` instead of the `Subparser class`.

Is there anyway to make it take the value from the `Subparser class` - in the `on_packet()` function? One constraint- I DO NOT KNOW WHAT `packet` looks like or where it comes from! So are we able to achieve this just from the above information?

Comment: You are passing subparser to parser, so why couldn't you access the version member ?
The tingling thing is about the choice of names, which is reversed.

Comment: What is stopping you from writing `self.version`?

Comment: `Parser` has an inherited `on_packet` method. What's the actual question?

Comment: Just like you don't need to explicitly define a passrhru `__init__`

Comment: How can **self.version** be initialized without **packet.game**?

Comment: Maybe if you showed how you wanted to use the parser, and illustrated an actual problem...

Comment: Иван Балва you are right! - let me add to the code

Comment: All amended now! - sorry the question didn't quite make sense at first, but now it should

Comment: `parse_er_data` returns `None` because you don't have a `return` statement.  It has nothing to do with inheritance.

Comment: Nothing inherits from `Context` anyway; nothing in your question *uses* `Context` unless we are supposed to assume that the `packet` argument to `Subparser.on_packet` is an instance of `Context`.

Comment: If there is a **Context** object, its attribute **version**, can be accessed like this: **object.version**.

Comment: Okay Chepner, I have edited the above- I am not intending to return anything; my intention is to use `self.version` in the code to follow, but as I have it above, when I hit the breakpoint() and I print self.version, it always produces None!

Comment: Иван Балван - what if I have a function within a class- like `on_packet()` in `class Subparser`, and I want to access something in `on_packet`- is there a syntax for this? From what I understand I would need to call on the function, but to do this I will need to know what `packet` is, which I don't!

Comment: You can set the **packet** parameter to None by default and allow **on_pocket** to return a dictionary of its variables `if packet==None`.

Comment: Thanks Иван Балван, that is a very good idea- but then would I need to call `on_packet()` in `parse_er_data()`?

Comment: Can I please trouble you to show what you mean in a solution? - as I part understand it by partly don't! - sorry still a bit of a newbie here :p

Comment: Yes, like `on_packet()['some_variable']`

Comment: Oh wow, I've not seen that syntax before..

Comment: So I change the above to `on_packet()[packet=None]`? And then in the body what do I write?

Comment: if **packet** is None, `on_packet()` is just a dictionary

Comment: It's not special syntax; it's just an indexing operation on whatever `on_packet` returns.

Comment: I really think you need to spend some time with [the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html); your question is full of fundamental misunderstandings of basic Python syntax and concepts.

Comment: Thanks for the link chepner- I am very much looking to improve and it looks like a useful tutorial

Comment: Okay, maybe I've not asked the right question. For the code above let's say that `packet.game == 1`, why is it that when I run the above code, I still get `None`? Should `1` not be printed, since I have `self.version = packet.game` ??

Comment: Do you call `print(temp)` after all the code and with no indentation? If so, what is **temp**?

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that I am running some file against the code above in my Python interpreter, and when we hit the `breakpoint()`, that is when I type in `print(temp)`. I defined `temp` in `parse_er_data()` function. 

To answer your question, no there is no indentation

Comment: What is the **breakpoint()**, where is it defined? What does it do? How does the **print** know, what the **temp** is? Because the **temp** that is defined in **parse_er_data()** exist only in this function, in its local scope.

Answer (score 0):

A way to get variables from a function scope:

```
def fun(x=None):
    a=1
    b=2
    if x==None:
        return {'a':a,'b':b}
    #... the rest of the function
    return #... te end

fun()['a'] #output 1
fun()['b'] #output 2
```

But i can't see a reason why anyone want to do it, yet... Your question was about **version** anyway, and **version** in **Context** is not that of **SubParser**

Comment: I don't think, that it is an answer to the question, so please unmark it, if possible. (It was to large to place it in the comment field)